# How to fix "com.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'taxi_id' "

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am a beginner to Spring Boot/JPA. Am trying to do CRUD operation for taxi model.

I get the following error :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
> 'taxi_id'

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my repository code:

```
package com.example.SpringBoot.Model.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.SpringBoot.Model.Taxi;

public interface DAO extends CrudRepository<Taxi, Integer>{
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.SpringBoot.Controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.SpringBoot.Model.Taxi;
import com.example.SpringBoot.Model.Repository.DAO;


@RestController
public class TaxiController {
    
    @Autowired
    public DAO repo;
        
    @PutMapping(path= "/Taxi" , produces = {"application/json"})
    public Taxi insertTaxi(Taxi taxi) {
        repo.save(taxi);
        return taxi;
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(path ="/Taxi/{TaxiId}")
    public void deleteTaxi(@RequestParam int TaxiId) {
        
        repo.deleteById(TaxiId);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path ="/Taxi")
    public List<Taxi> displayTaxi() {
        return (List<Taxi>) repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Model class

```
package com.example.SpringBoot.Model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Taxi {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int TaxiId;
    private String TaxiType;
    

    public int getTaxiId() {
        return TaxiId;
    }

    
    public void setTaxiId(int taxiId) {
        TaxiId = taxiId;
    }

    public String getTaxiType() {
        return TaxiType;
    }

    public void setTaxiType(String taxiType) {
        TaxiType = taxiType;
    }
}
```

SQL server code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Taxi](
[Taxiid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TaxiType] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[TaxiId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stack trace:

```
    .   ____          _            __ _ _
    /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
    \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
    =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
    :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-06-03 15:37:24.554  INFO 7808 --- [           main] c.e.SpringBoot.TaxiBookingApplication    : Starting TaxiBookingApplication on IMCHLT080 with PID 7808 (D:\workspace\TaxiBooking\target\classes started by vignesh_nithin in D:\workspace\TaxiBooking
.............
2019-06-03 15:37:34.446  INFO 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-03 15:37:34.456  INFO 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-06-03 15:37:34.530  INFO 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-06-03 15:37:34.645  WARN 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2019-06-03 15:37:34.645 ERROR 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'taxi_id'.
2019-06-03 15:37:34.668 ERROR 7808 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'taxi_id'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:548) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:479) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
```

I expect the Taxi table data to be displayed/inserted/deleted based on the URL being hit.

Comment: add @Column("name = TaxId") or change default naming strategy. More information you can find in https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: Well why do you call it `TaxiId` in the schema but `Taxiid` in the code?

Comment: @Lukasz thanks. that approach works.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I pasted a wrong SQL code, I was making some changes in SQL server. but then earlier it was "TaxiId" in both java as well as SQL and was not working earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your persistence config by default seems to translate camelcase by separating it with an underscore. So if you have:

```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int TaxiId;
```

it will try to use: 'taxi_id';

As on db you have:

```
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Taxi](
        [Taxiid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

you should either change the field name to: 'Taxiid' or explicitly name the column:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "Taxiid")
 private int TaxiId;
```

You may also try to change the default naming strategy used by altering accordingly these properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy
```